# Run cron job with curl to execute django command management

Tags: django, docker, kubernetes, cron, kubernetes-cronjob

I have a command management that I should run daily at midnight, I usually execute it from my pc, I want to create a cronjob that can do this automatically
here the command that I execute from my local environment:

```
env=application; kubectl exec -ti $(kubectl get pods| grep $env| awk '{print $1}') -c "application" --  ./manage.py daily_job
```

and here the corn job yml file that I wrote:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: update-client-tasks
  labels:
    environment: application
spec:
  schedule: "0 0 * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          containers:
            - name: update-client-tasks
              image: gcr.io/application-156608/application:v0.5.32
              args:
                - /usr/bin/curl --data "key=$CRON_KEY" http://application/code/ | env=application; kubectl exec -ti $(kubectl get pods| grep $env| awk '{print $1}') -c "application" --  ./manage.py daily_job
              env:
                - name: CRON_KEY
                  valueFrom:
                    secretKeyRef:
                      name: application-secrets
                      key: cronKey
```

when running this corn job I got this error:

```
2021-06-22 09:00:24.184 JSTTraceback (most recent call last): File "manage.py", line 10, in <module> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line utility.execute() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute django.setup() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate app_config = AppConfig.create(entry) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create module = import_module(entry) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_extensions'
```

please any help will be very useful

**N.B: update**

and to resolve this problem of django extensions
I changed the `args` in the yaml file

```yaml
args:
                - /usr/bin/curl --data "key=$CRON_KEY" http://application/code/ | env=application; kubectl exec -ti $(kubectl get pods| grep $env| awk '{print $1}') -c "application" --  pip3 install django-extensions && python3 manage.py daily_job
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
django.setup()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
module = import_module(entry)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_extensions'
```

some have downvoted my question due to lack of explication and unclear details,
I really apologize about that, as myself, do not understand well kubernetes and having troubles to understand the documentation

Comment: In case you did not actually read the error message, a module is missing in your environment to execute your python file (i.e. `django_extenstions`). Now, what is your question exactly? Which debugging steps/attempts did you make to either understand why this module is not found if you believe it is there or to install it if it is missing?

Comment: I tried this: `/usr/bin/curl --data "key=$CRON_KEY" http://application/code/ | env=application; kubectl exec -ti $(kubectl get pods| grep $env| awk '{print $1}') -c "application" --  python3 manage.py daily_job` but always the same error

Comment: Please do not add needed precisions to answer your question in volatile comments: [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68646492/edit). I also suggest you read [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal complete vefiable example](/help/mcve)

Comment: sorry about that

Comment: Instead of trying to use `kubectl exec` here, can you directly run `python3 manage.py daily_job` as the CronJob's command?  (What should happen if there are multiple matching replicas; does the maintenance job need to run in all of them?)

Comment: @DavidMaze do you mean this command: `/usr/bin/curl --data "key=$CRON_KEY" http://application/code/ | env=application; python3 manage.py daily_job`

Comment: Just `./manage.py daily_job`.  If you need some credential, set the environment variable directly in the Job from a Secret.